# Meteor update to 0.6.1 issues

Tags: meteor

I was prompted to update my meteor from 0.5.4 to 0.6.1 today and when I updated I lost all of the code I had created earlier in the day. I tried using meteor --release 0.5.4 to get back to the previous version but I get the error message "unknown release" this was the release I had before.

Has anyone else had this issue and if so, how did you resolve it?

Thank you for your help!
Judy

Answer (score 1):

"meteor --release x.y.z" will only work with releases >= 0.6.0. So you can go back to 0.6.0 using that mechanism but not anything earlier than 0.6.0.

If you want to use an earlier release. You can edit smart.lock (smart.lock exists if you are using meteorite. If you are not using meteorite I'm not sure how easy it is to switch between releases of meteor) and change the commit property for meteor to use the commit for 0.5.4. It should be commit: 2d27799008fb87a06d4119c48097aa382d230b61

So you should have this is your smart.lock:

```
"meteor": {
    "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git",
    "branch": "master",
    "commit": "2d27799008fb87a06d4119c48097aa382d230b61"
}
```

Comment: Simpler would be:

    "meteor": {
        "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git",
        "tag": "v0.5.4"
    }